# Hide group separator in shell

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

Im working on a .NET MAUI app using shell for menu and routing and i need to hide the separation line between flyoutitem and menuitem. Im using menuitems to have the back arrow in the title bar, so it calls the GoToAsync() in code behind.

Other than that, two hiden shellcontent items.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zelMO.png)

Here is the XAML code

```
<ShellContent
        Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" 
        FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate loading:LoadingPage}"
        Route="loading"
        Title="Loading"
        />
    
    <ShellContent
        Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
        FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate landing:LandingPage}"
        Route="landing" />
    <ShellContent
        FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
        Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate startupPage:LoginPage}"
        Route="login" />

    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" FlyoutItem.IsVisible="True"
                >
        <ShellContent
        Icon="icon_home"
        Title="{utils:Localized FlyoutHomeLabel}"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" 
        Route="home"
         />
    </FlyoutItem>
   
    <MenuItem
        Clicked="MenuItem_UserDataClicked"
        Text="User Data"
        IconImageSource="icon_userdata"/>
    <MenuItem
        Clicked="MenuItem_TermsClicked"
        Text="Terms.."
        IconImageSource="icon_terms"
        />
    <MenuItem
        Clicked="MenuItem_SettingsClicked"
        Text="Settings"
        IconImageSource="icon_settings"
        />

    <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="50,*" Padding="10">
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance!

Hide/style the group separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the method `FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems"` in the `FlyoutItem`. This method will group the flyout item by using the separator line.